# Typeing Map and Set for structured data

Tags: typescript

In typescript one can do:

```js
type Foo = string[]
```

but sometimes one wants to model more structured "object like" data and then one can do:

```js
type Bar = [[name: string],[age:number],[consent:boolean]]
```

`Map` is defined as `Map<K, V>` in lib.es2015.collection.d.ts and that's simlar to how `Foo` is defined above.  How would one type a `Map` similar to `Bar` above?

```js
const map1 = new Map();
map1.set("name",'bob');
map1.set("age",102);
map1.set("consent",true);

 // as map1's type is { name: string, age: number, consent, boolean } - the compliler
 // should be able to determine the type is `string`
const shouldBeString = map1.get("name");
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4EYYF4ZgKYHcYCyyAFAJQDcAUIqgHQTZTEBEYCc2zANAOQBGIPjwrVkKeoxYIA5py4oADACYRNcQybNQkbGCjcoAJwCu2EZRgB6SzAQR4YnvagBPJNhgBLewG8s7bAAuGGhDTzBpLltZYLBjOD5sQyjtBj0ogRAAG2wEMBgAXxgAWhgoAAsPUDgkLM8cwwtrEPKQYyyAExhE2z4cspAYDsYkuHCPCom3D28YAANQ8Ok5ylTYCFb2joAhbABlIyWMBzpZTTYOZgogA)

Comment: IIRC, it's not possible. Use an object instead.

Comment: What does `[[name: string], [age: number], [consent: boolean]]` mean to you?  In TypeScript that's a tuple of one-tuples, and the labels `name`, `age`, and `consent`, are unobservable in the type system.  It's essentially `[[string],[number],[boolean]]`, a subtype of `Array<[string] | [number] | [boolean]>`, which is... weird.  Are you just trying to represent `{name: string; age: number; consent: boolean}`?  If so, can you [edit] to say that instead (and presumably `type Foo = {[k: string]: string}`?)  If not, can you explain what you're talking about?

Comment: And where does `Set` show up in this question other than the title?  There's no key-value mapping in `Set`s, so what is the issue you have  with it?

Comment: @jcalz, thank you, yes that looks like the solution. - so this is a duplicate.